# ¿Se puede saber cuándo Stack Overflow está fuera de línea por mantenimiento?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Estaba escribiendo un comentario en una pregunta cuando de repente la página se quedó en blanco.

Cuando le di a refrescar me salió algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen dice que **está fuera de línea por mantenimiento**. De hecho le di a refrescar varias veces y seguían saliendo en pantalla esos códigos extraños.

Al cabo de un minuto más o menos todo volvió a la normalidad, aunque se notaba más lento de lo habitual.

¿Hay forma de saber cuándo hay mantenimientos programados?

¿Por qué se mostrará esa imagen tan extraña en lugar de un simple mensaje de *fuera de servicio por mantenimiento*?

Comment: no es un bug, esa pantalla es una cosa artística -si se quiere-, si quieres estar informado del status de la red puedes seguir a [@stackstatus](https://twitter.com/stackstatus)

Comment: @EmanuelVe En ese enlace no informan de la caida de hoy. Y en 
[Stack Exchange Network Status](http://stackstatus.net/) tampoco. En cualquier caso, tanto si ha sido una caída no programada como una operación de mantenimiento no anunciada, la gente de SO es muy rápida, el sitio ha vuelto muy pronto.